# C# - How to return a cursor from an Oracle procedure inside a package

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-procedures, package

## Package

#### Package Declaration

This is the package declaration (*Oracle 9i*):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE MyPackage AS

    PROCEDURE Results(start_date IN DATE, end_date IN DATE, brand IN NUMBER, summary OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);

END MyPackage;
```

#### Package Body

This is the package body with the procedure:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY MyPackage AS

    PROCEDURE Results(start_date IN DATE, end_date IN DATE, brand IN NUMBER, summary OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
        BEGIN
        OPEN summary FOR
            SELECT NVL(id, 0), type, order, SUM(alpha), SUM(beta), SUM(gamma), SUM(delta), SUM(epsilon), SUM(zeta), SUM(eta), SUM(theta), SUM(iota), SUM(kappa), SUM(lambda)
            FROM sample_owner.sample_table
            WHERE fecha BETWEEN start_date AND end_date AND id = brand
            GROUP BY id, type, order
            ORDER BY id, type, order;
        END Results;

END MyPackage;
```

## Code

Here is how I try to retrieve the cursor in C# (using *System.Data.OracleClient* in *.NET 2.0*):

```cs
public static DataSet getResults(DateTime beginning, DateTime ending, int myBrand)
{

    string cs = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost)(PORT=myport))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=myservicename)));User ID=cat;Password=dog;Persist Security Info=True";
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cs);
    OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "MyPackage.Results";
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("start_date", OracleType.DateTime).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
    cmd.Parameters["start_date"].Value = beginning;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("end_date", OracleType.DateTime).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
    cmd.Parameters["end_date"].Value = ending;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("brand", OracleType.Int32).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
    cmd.Parameters["brand"].Value = myBrand;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("summary", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("testDS");
        new OracleDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        conn.Close();
        return ds;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
        return null;
    }

}
```

And here are the values that I'm using to make the call:

```cs
int myBrand = 1;
DateTime beginning = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);
DateTime ending = new DateTime(2014, 1, 31);
DataSet myDataSet = getResults(beginning, ending, myBrand);
```

The dataset returns empty, and I'm not receiving any error messages.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At the first glance I don't see any wrongdoing besides not using ODP.NET for this. Does your query return values if executed separately, directly in oracle?

Comment: @T.S. The query returns values when executed directly in Oracle (I'm using Oracle SQL Developer) I've used ODP.NET in the past, but I'm not allowed to use it in this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I see your issue. Try this:

```
string cs = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost)(PORT=myport))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=myservicename)));User ID=cat;Password=dog;Persist Security Info=True";

using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cs))
{
    using (OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {

        cmd.CommandText = "MyPackage.Results";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("start_date", OracleType.DateTime).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters["start_date"].Value = beginning;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("end_date", OracleType.DateTime).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters["end_date"].Value = ending;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("brand", OracleType.Int32).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters["brand"].Value = myBrand;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("summary", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
            OracleDataAdapter a = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("testDS");
            a.TableMappings.Add("MyTable", "sample_table"); // possible need for this
            a.Fill(ds);

            return ds;
        }
        catch 
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
 }
```

Note that when you use `using (OracleConnection...` you need not to worry about closing connection because it is closed when `Dispose` called on IDisposable.

Comment: You were right from the start; there was nothing wrong with the code; we refreshed and restarted everything and were finally able to see the data in the dataset visualizer. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @AtanasMendes Glad it worked for you. Your code should execute, besides that you had some extra in it that you don't need :o)) Did you try my code?

Comment: I did and it worked too, using "using" helped me get rid of some of the clutter